# Positioning 'Buy Now' buttons below my 'Featured Products' widgets on WooCommerce?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having a bit of trouble with a 'Featured Products' area I'm trying to set up on my child theme. I've used a PHP loop to get the featured products to show. I've been styling them succesfully up until this final bit, where I've floated the images left to position them next to each other, but this seems to of floated the 'Buy Now' buttons as well. I've tried to clear: left but no luck. Any ideas?

HTML/PHP:

```
           <div class="featured-products">
           <h1 class="featured-products">Featured Products</h1>
           <?php
            $meta_query   = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'   => '_featured',
                'value' => 'yes'
            );
            $args = array(
                'post_type'   =>  'product',
                'stock'       =>  1,
                'showposts'   =>  4,
                'orderby'     =>  'date',
                'order'       =>  'DESC',
                'meta_query'  =>  $meta_query
            );

            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

                <li>    
                    <?php 
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID ) ) 
                            echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog' ); 
                        else 
                            echo '<img class="image-featured" src="' . woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() . ' />'; 
                    ?>

                    <?php 
                        woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product );
                    ?>    
                </li>

        <?php 
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query(); 
        ?>
        </div>
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query(); 
        ?>
```

CSS:

```
a.button.add_to_cart_button.alt {
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #95020a;
    clear: left;
}

.featured-products img {
    width: 270px;
    height: 180px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

I assumed it'd be a simple fix of just clearing the floats but I've now been scratching my head for 20 minutes trying to work it out.

Cheers for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below mentioned css:

```
.featured-products li{float:left; margin-left:20px;}
```

and edit `css` property of image

```
.featured-products img{ height: 180px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 270px;
display:block;
}
```

edit this also:

```
a.button.add_to_cart_button.alt {
    background-color: #95020a;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you explain what I had done wrong so I can learn as well? Cheers.

Comment: Cheers for the edit, was just about to ask about how to resolve them hovering over the products haha. (; I'm guessing to center them beneath the products all I need to do is add a left margin?

Comment: remove `margin-left` property from `<img>` and `<a>` tag and add `margin-left` on `<li>` tag.